Probability distribution of portfolio loss
I was trying to do this exercise, and something doesn't quite add up. We need to calculate,with reference to a time horizon of one year the expected number of defaults and the probability of default equal to the expected number of defaults for a portfolio consisting of 200 loans, each with probability of default(PD) equal to 1%. It is suggested that the Poisson distribution be used. This is how I computed the expected number of defaults $E(D) = n\times PD = 200\times0.01 = 2$
Using the poisson I computed the probability of default equal to the expected number of defaults(2) as $P(X=2) = \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!}$ = $\frac{2^2 e^{-2}}{2!}$ = 0.27
What is not clear is in the next point:
making use of the probability of the previous point and assuming that losses are directly proportional to the number of defaults in the amount of 20000, complete the probability distribution of portfolio loss given below:
\begin{matrix}
\textbf{Amount} & \textbf{Probability} \\
0 & 0.16 \\
20000 & ? \\
40000 & ? \\
60000 & 0.22 \\
80000 & 0.08 \\
100000 & 0.02 \\
\end{matrix}
Can someone help me to fill this table?
If the initial value in the table(no default ) is associated with a probability of 0.16% , my answer in the first point could not be right because $P(X=0) \frac{\lambda^x e^{\lambda}}{x!} = e^{-2}= 0.135$
Then the probability of X=1 which is equal to X=2 is $P(X=1) \frac{\lambda^x e^{\lambda}}{x!} = \lambda e^{-2}= 0.27$
If we add these probabilities to those in the table, however, it goes beyond the value 1. How can I tackle this problem?

Although I don't quite follow the question--"losses are directly proportional to the number of defaults in the amount of 20000" is hard to parse--I can tell you that assuming this table is intended to give Poisson probabilities for outcomes 0, 1, ..., 5, there does not exist any Poisson distribution with the four probabilities listed here, even allowing for the imprecision of just two decimal places.

yes it is not clear to me either. i thought that 20000 is associated with X=1, 40000 with X=2 and so on. I cannot understand how these already given probabilities are calculated

loss severity is 20000, so for your table you have to produce Poisson distribution PMF for x=0..5. You can backout $\lambda=-\ln 0.16$, then plug it into Poisson PMF function.

so in this case $\lambda = 1.833$ . if we try to use this value with a number of defaults equal to 3 we have: $\frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!} = \frac{1.833^3 e^{-1.833}}{3!} = 0.16$ which is still different from the one associated in the table (0.22)

As I pointed out in a comment to the question, there does not exist any Poisson pmf that agrees with the posted probabilities.
